# Extent Reports are not generated as Bamboo artifacts.Logs are created

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, bamboo-artifacts

When I run my code Java Selenium Maven project locally It generates Extent reports.But when the same is run through Bamboo it is not publishing Extent reports.Only logs are published.

I tried different copy patterns.Still it doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.